# Getting Error while working with Charts in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, victory-native

Im trying to make a Donut Chart in react native app and I have tried Libreries like Victory-native and react-native-gifted-charts. None of these works for me. They all are giving similar kind of error like that none of these file exist:[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wofB8.png)

[Error screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwXDH.png)

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { BarChart, LineChart, PieChart, PopulationPyramid } from "react-native-gifted-charts";

const App = () => {
  const data=[ {value:50}, {value:80}, {value:90}, {value:70} ]
  return (
    <View>
      <BarChart data = {data} horizontal />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Comment: Have you followed every instruction in the docs? Looks like you're missing dependencies in `node_modules`.

Comment: yes I have followed everything, it giving some typescript related error